# How do I add the repository for Unity?

Tags: apt, unity, repository, error-handling, echo

This is the command I am trying to run:

```
sudo sh -c echo deb "https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'
```

I am trying to install unity to work on games. this command is supposed to make my PC recognize the repository. The command keeps returning the answer `E: Unable to locate package unityhub`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Missing `'` before `echo` and moved a `"` before `deb`:

`sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'`

Explanation:

- you need to execute through `sudo sh -c` all the commands that follow, so the command must be embraced in quotes. There is no parameter expansion, so single quotes are ok.
- the string to be `echo`ed must be enclosed as well. In this case better use a double quote, so it is not confused by bash as termination of the command to be executed by `sh -c`.

I would simplify the command in the following way: `echo "deb https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list`, because you need `sudo` only when writing to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have follow the next instructions:

```
wget -o- https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/keys/public

file public

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./unity_keyring.gpg --import public

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./unity_keyring.gpg --export > ./unity-archive-keyring.gpg

sudo mv ./unity-archive-keyring.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/

sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install unityhub
```

Source: [link to unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/keyring-error.1290203/#post-8293259)